# Twitter-Bootstrap Modal not working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I had created a modal dialogue

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" id="LaunchDemo">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

i just called the modal from..

```
$("a#LaunchDemo").click();
```

but the modal is just `blinking` on the screen, i also called the modal through button click .same problem iam getting , where i went wrong?,Please help ..

Comment: $('#myModal').modal('show'); it worked

Comment: Make sure you are loading Bootstrap.js at the **bottom of the page** before the closing body tag. You won't need to write a line of JS if you do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute your javascript code when the DOM is fully loaded. And use `modal` instead of `click`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#LaunchDemo').modal(options)
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1998/

Answer (score 0):

It wrong when the with of model was too big.

You can try when set the stylesheet for modal class in bootstrap file {width:900}

It will happen....

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the class `hide` from the modal div:
`<div id="myModal" class="modal`<strike>`hide`</strike>`fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the **href="#myModal"** in the hyperlink tag because that is trying to link you to a part of the page.

Also, you shouldn't need to specify the element type in your selector. It will be faster to just search for the element by ID.

Comment: Incorrect. Via the bootstrap page you can target the div in an href. This is the from the bootstrap page.

Activate a modal without writing JavaScript. Set data-toggle="modal" on a controller element, like a button, along with a data-target="#foo" or href="#foo" to target a specific modal to toggle.